# php issues returning query

Tags: php, sql, string

So I have my query in which I am trying to get the "password" field to return because I am having issues with my login:

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT `password` FROM users WHERE username = 'joeybab3'");
```

and I get the error :

> "object of class mysql_result cannot be converted to a string"

So some googling got me this:

```
list($res) = $res->fetch_row;
```

but that just returns blank when I use echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli::query` method returns a `mysqli_result` object. It is an object, that's why you cannot use echo to print it out.

You need to use fetch_array/fetch_assoc/fetch_row methods to really get the data out of it.

In this case, you could use:

```
$row = $res->fetch_assoc(); 
$password = $row['password'];
echo $password;
```

Comment: Thanks, I can now continue onward with a login system on my site!

Answer (score 0):

fetch_row is a function, calling it like this should work.

```
list($res) = $res->fetch_row();
```

Edit:

Looks like you're using the MySQL library which has been deprecated. You should [choose a different api](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Then use this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'password' FROM users WHERE username = 'joeybab3'";
```

and echo `$sql`.

This is how I would do it.